# The type or namespace name 'ObservableCollection' could not be found in .net 2.0

Tags: c#, observablecollection

I am getting the below error when try to use ObservableCollection in .net 2.0 framework

**Error 3   The type or namespace name 'ObservableCollection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

i knew following assemblies are needed to use ObservableCollection. but am using .net 2.0 framework. so no windowsBase.dll there in 2.0 framework.

```
in WindowsBase.dll (.NET 3.x)
in System.dll (.NET 4.x)
in System.Windows.dll (Silverlight/Windows Phone 7)
in System.ObjectModel.dll (WinRT) (included in ".NET for Windows Store apps")
```

how can i resolve the issue .net 2.0 framework. is there any way 
?

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: msdn says it is only in 3.0 and up http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx

Comment: As @Anton said, this is only available in .NET 3.0 and later.  So you can't use it in a 2.0 application.